# Python - 2 Equations In 1 Loop

Tags: python

I'm a beginner with Python and trying to learn how to put 2 equations into 1 loop.

```
months = paymentTerm * 12
startingMonth = 1
while startingMonth <= months :     
    print(startingMonth)
    startingMonth = startingMonth + 1

principal = principalAmount
startingPrincipal = principalAmount - monthlyInterest
while startingPrincipal <= principal :
    print(startingPrincipal)
    startingPrincipal = startingPrincipal - monthlyInterest
```

Any ideas on how? Essentially I want the outputs to print side by side while using the \t\t function because the values for my principal are printing after the months, but I want them to be side by side. Thank you!!

Comment: Please post your code here as text, not as an image.

Comment: use the Code Sample to post the code.

Comment: Can you be more explicit in what you mean by "put 2 equations into 1 loop"? I can sort of infer given the problem but do you mean having two conditionals like: `while (startingPrincipal <= principal) and (startingMonth <= months)`: ...?

Comment: You can store your input in 2 different lists and then print them linearly.

Answer (score 0):

Check for both conditions in the `while` condition.

```
while startingMonth <= months and startingPrincipal <= principal:
    print(startingMonth, startingPrincipal)
    startingMonth += 1
    startingPrincipal += monthlyInterest
```

This will stop when either limit is reached.

Answer (score 0):

Zero, Welcome!

First, this code won't run -- Please considering posting code that runs (although if it doesn't that's fine but your question should reflect that issue).  Second, this problem can not be solve the way you think it can (as it appears to me).

This is probably the closest approximation of what you are looking for.  By declaring the booleans up from, you can determine if you should start that loop, and at each iteration, it can be determined which process to apply.

```
months = paymentTerm * 12
startingMonth = 1

t: bool = startingMonth <= months
p: bool = startingPrincipal <= principal


while t or p:

    if t:
        print(startingMonth)
        startingMonth += 1

    if p:
        print(startingPrincipal)
        startingPrincipal -= monthlyInterest

    t = startingMonth <= months
    p = startingPrincipal <= principal
```

you can also use the fancy walrus operator too!

```
months = paymentTerm * 12
startingMonth = 1

while (t := startingMonth <= months) or (p := startingPrincipal <= principal):

    if t:
        print(startingMonth)
        startingMonth += 1

    if p:
        print(startingPrincipal)
        startingPrincipal -= monthlyInterest
```